# Pandas groupby conditional subtraction

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column based on a conditional subtraction. I want to first group the dataframe from column A, then take the row value of C where B is minimum, and subtract that value from all values in column C.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
["R", 1, 2],
["R", 2, 4],
["R", 3, 6],
["R", 4, 8],
["S", 0, 5],
["S", 1, 4],
["S", 2, 1],
["S", 3, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["a", "b", "c"])
df

Out[1]:
    a   b   c
0   R   1   2
1   R   2   4
2   R   3   6
3   R   4   8
4   S   0   5
5   S   1   4
6   S   2   1
7   S   3   3
```

Want it to yield the column 'd' of:

```
Out[2]:
    a   b   c    d
0   R   1   2    0
1   R   2   4    2
2   R   3   6    4
3   R   4   8    6
4   S   0   5    0
5   S   1   4   -1
6   S   2   1   -4
7   S   3   3   -2
```

Anyone have any nice pythonic ways of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
In [591]: df['d'] = df['c'] - df.loc[df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('idxmin'), 'c'].values

In [592]: df
Out[592]:
   a  b  c  d
0  R  1  2  0
1  R  2  4  2
2  R  3  6  4
3  R  4  8  6
4  S  0  5  0
5  S  1  4 -1
6  S  2  1 -4
7  S  3  3 -2
```

Comment: Just validating yours (-: checks out.

Comment: How about `df.assign(d=df.c - df.groupby('a').b.transform(lambda d: df.c[d.idxmin()]))`

Comment: Over small data, about the same time.  Only stylistic difference.

Comment: in my current case the `lambda` version (i.e. comment) seems to be slower by a factor of ~3 while your (@piRSquared) posted answer with `map` and the accepted answer are more or less equal.

Answer (score 5):

```
conditional_c = df.groupby('a').b.idxmin().map(df.c)
df.assign(d=df.c - df.a.map(conditional_c))

   a  b  c  d
0  R  1  2  0
1  R  2  4  2
2  R  3  6  4
3  R  4  8  6
4  S  0  5  0
5  S  1  4 -1
6  S  2  1 -4
7  S  3  3 -2
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quit efficient, but work

```
df['d']=df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x : x['c']-x['c'][x['b']==x['b'].min()].values).values
df
Out[1305]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  R  1  2  0
1  R  2  4  2
2  R  3  6  4
3  R  4  8  6
4  S  0  5  0
5  S  1  4 -1
6  S  2  1 -4
7  S  3  3 -2
```